# Bigger x-axis range in seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I'm plotting a bar graph with matplotlib/seaborn and the range is the min/max values, plus it skips values that have 0 counts. How can I both pad the range and not skip 0 values?

```
# bar
ax2 = figDayMonth.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2 = sns.countplot(x=np.asarray(dayMonth), palette="pastel")
ax2.set_title('Days of Month Counts', FontSize=20)
ax2.tick_params(labelsize=15)
ax2.set_ylabel("Count", FontSize=16)
ax2.set_xlabel("Day of Month", FontSize=16)
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True, top=True, right=True)
plt.show()
print(2*'\n')
```

[image]

`dayMonth` is a list of integers with the above counts. Although for example there are no 2, 29, or 30 values, I'd still like the graph to reserve a place for those values.

I tried `ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(32))` but that just seems to squeeze my graph to the left without changing the x-axis values.

Comment: May you add enough code to run it and see the problem?

Comment: Well the `dayMonth` list comes from extracting file timestamps from an external HD path so I don't think it would be useful

Comment: What is `dayMonth`? Does it have the days with 0 counts in it? You may want to read and understand [mcve].

Comment: `dayMonth` is just a list of integers with the counts shown above. It can't contain the 0 counts or they would no longer be 0. Was hoping somebody experienced with mpl/seaborn would immediately recognize my error. I'll try to write some code to generate fake data so this can be run shortly.

Comment: "Was hoping somebody experienced with mpl/seaborn would immediately recognize my error." Even if someone immediately sees what you are doing wrong, without reproducible example, they have to go to the trouble to generate data to demonstrate how to fix the problem. By creating a reproducible example, you are saving them that effort and increasing your own chance of getting help.

Comment: I didn't ask for a plot output though just the line of code that would fix this. To be honest I'm not that experienced with python to generate fake data that easily.

Comment: Then it sounds like it would be a good learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you want to plot a histogram of the input list. That histogram can be created using

```
x = np.arange(1,33)
plt.hist(dayMonth, bins=x)
```

A full example would be

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dayMonth = [1,3,12,30,2,3,12,16,18,31,3,13,16,18,30,1,3,12,16,18,30]
x = np.arange(1,33)    
_,_,bars = plt.hist(dayMonth, bins=x, align="left")

colors=sns.color_palette(palette="pastel", n_colors=len(x))
for color, bar in zip(colors, bars):
    bar.set_color(color)
plt.gca().set_xlim(-1,32)
plt.xticks(x[:-1])
plt.show()
```

[image]